# Image sizes for display in an app - trying to reduce the size of images

Tags: ios, uiimageview, photoshop

I hope this is the right place to post a question like this. Apologies if it isnt. I am having an issue displaying images. I want to display 10 images in a `UIScrollView` with paging enabled which are roughly 1mb in size.I am using lazy loading based on this example: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content . Is there a way to reduce there size that will keep as much quality as possible? It does not need to be done in code either, if there was a good compression site that could do it it would be great. I dont have much experience dealing with images.

For example what should i be looking out for?

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612131/whats-the-easiest-way-to-resize-optimize-an-image-size-with-the-iphone-sdk

Comment: possible duplicate of [Present and zoom large images on iOS without CATiledLayer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996268/present-and-zoom-large-images-on-ios-without-catiledlayer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit images both programmatically and using other applications. If you optimize the images by code you will anyhow have to store it in the app thus increasing the size of the application so it is better to optimize and then add it to the project.

As easy to use website to optimize images is https://tinypng.com/

Comment: See my answer below, make the file size smaller does not decrease the memory usage of an `UIImage` object.

Comment: Thanks @rckoenes I had not known this.

Comment: @rckoenes thanks for the advise. Is it true however that there is optimisation in the iOS system for png images? So the smaller the png the quicker?

Comment: @Gman Yes and No, read [Image Decompression Benchmark](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/12/image-decompression-benchmark-ipad-4-mini/) blog posted. There is some optimization, but not always in the way you expect. Also all images type go by the same rule for memory usage. If you need to get you memory usage down, use small image in resolution.

Comment: @rckoenes thanks! Ill have a read. Is there any negative/noticable effect if I only use standard images in both the iPhone 4 and iPhone 5? I am assuming pixilation will occur?

Comment: No since the iPhone 4 and 5 are both retina screens.

Comment: @rckoenes this may seem like a 'noob' questions but are '@2x' required for an app? Or is it only optional

Comment: @2x is required by apple.

Answer (score 1):

Use [slender mac app](http://dragonforged.com/slender/) for `removing unwanted files` and `resizing image`. Its `handy application` in `every manner`.

**EDIT** : Best tool for resizing images is [imageOptim](http://imageoptim.com/) does the same and is free.

Comment: Making the file size smaller does **not** make the loaded image in memory any smaller.

Comment: yes it makes [UIImage imageNamed:@""] caches exact amount of size of image;

Comment: Any image load in a `UIImage` object will make it bitmapped, thus thus the size of the image in memory is `height x width x 4 bytes`. The 4 bytes are red, green, blue and alpha. So even though the size on the file system might be less when loaded in memory it will be the same.

Comment: I downloaded the trial of Slender Mac app - very useful too regardless

Answer (score 0):

try Photoshop save as web & devices and save as PNG or jpg, and check the quality of both, you will be surprised.